# Show doc file from BLOB MySQL in JSP using Struts

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts, blob

I need to retrieve a .doc file from MySQL DB where it is stored as a BLOB data type. This is my action file code

```
List<CandyDetails> det = new ArrayList<CandyDetails>();
CandyDetails details = new CandyDetails();

ResultSet rs3 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM seek_resume WHERE seek_code = '"+seekCode+"'");
   while(rs3.next()){
      details.setResume(rs3.getBytes(2));
}

request.setAttribute("candyDet", det);
return mapping.findForward("success");
```

This is CandyDetails.java file

```
private byte[] resume;
//getter/setter methods
```

This is my JSP page code

```
<logic:iterate name="candyDet" id="in">
     ${in.resume}
</logic:iterate>
```

The output I get on the jsp page is some gibberish

```
[B@3efc0688
```

The digits after B@ seem to be changing every time I refresh.

I'm using Struts 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside an Action class

```
String qry="SELECT * FROM seek_resume WHERE seek_code = '"+seekCode+"'"";
Statement st = con.createStatement(qry);                
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()) //show one document
{
    byte[] bytearray = new byte[1048576];
    int size=0;
    InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(2);
   // String contentType=rs.getString("content_type");
    String contentType = "application/msword"; //doc
    String contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; //docx                     
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    while((size=is.read(bytearray))!= -1 )
    {
        response.getOutputStream().write(bytearray,0,size);
    }
}

//return null;
```

----------jsp--------

```
<a href="showDoc.do?seekCode=${seekCode}" target="_blank"> View</a>
```

//put your link as you require.

Call the action class by passing the code  to the action class will inturn give you the doc as response.

OR

You can use Apache POI to display the doc as inline content.